# Error attaching database - "The database cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm getting the following error when I try to attach a database from a .mdf file:

> The database cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported

I did a little research and found out that version 706 is a database file from SQL Server 2012, and version 665 is a database file from SQL Server 2008R2

But the weird thing is that I'm using SQL Server Express 2014. Anyone know what I can do about that, shouldn't that work?

Comment: What does this return? `SELECT @@VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously trying to attach the database to a 2008 instance. Your local SSMS might be 2014 but the actual server you're working with is 2008.

Try

`SELECT @@VERSION`

to find out which version is the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the compatibility level, worked for me.
From here [The database cannot be opened because it is version 782. This server supports version 706 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346647/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-782-this-server-supports-ve)

Verify what level it is

USE VJ_DATABASE;
GO
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'VJ_DATABASE';
GO

Then make it compatible with the older version

```
ALTER DATABASE VJ_DATABASE
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;   
GO

100 = Sql Server 2008
110 = Sql Server 2012
120 = Sql Server 2014
```

By default, Sql Server 2014 will change the db versions compatibility to only 2014, using the @@ version you should be able to tell, which version Sql Server is.

Then run the command above to change it the version you have.

*Additional step: Ensure you look at the accessibility of the DB is not reset, do this by right clicking on properties of the folder and the database. (make sure you have rights so you don't get an access denied)*