# Using / Saving / Exporting SQL Server 2014 database to be used with VS 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have created a database in SQL Server 2014 but I don't see it in Visual Studio 2013. I've been trying to figure this out for days to no avail. How can I use the database I created in SSMS in VS 2013? or how can I export it to be used in VS 13?

If I try to open the database from SSMS data folder I get an error. "you don't have permission ..."

But if I copy the `.mdf` file somewhere else and try to open it I get this error:

> db cannot be opened because it is version 782. This server supports version 706 and earlier. a downgrade path is not supported

Any help would really be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to create a connection to your SQL Server 2014 instance from within VS 2013 no problem - and then you should see all your databases. That's the *preferred way* of doing things - stop fiddling and copying around `.mdf` files - SQL Server is a **server-based** system - and that's a **good thing!**  Leave those databases **on the server** and just connect to them....

Comment: The other error comes from the fact that VS 2013 ships with SQL Server **2012** Express - which is internal database version 706. You ***cannot*** under any circumstances take a SQL Server **2014** database (internal version: 782) and attach (or restore) it to a SQL Server **2012** instance - that's just not supported. Again: just leave the database *on the server* and you have no such issues!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The database cannot be opened because it is version 782. This server supports version 706 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346647/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-782-this-server-supports-ve)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the most recent version of SQL Server Data Tools (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)?  I believe it's been updated since initial release to support SQL 2014.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for quick response. I found the answer already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346647/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-782-this-server-supports-ve

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I will leave the db alone where it is. I have SSMS 2014 and vs 2013. I thankfully did the following

" Try changing Tools>Options>Data Connections>Database Tools>Data Connections>SQL Server Instance Name. The default for VS2013 is "(LocalDB)\v11.0". Changing to "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB", for example, seems to work - no more version 782 error."

As from the above link(answer) posted by user1723033 and VikciaR and all is working for now.

Thanks again for your help.