# Can't Open Database, Wrong Version

Tags: database, visual-studio-2015, version, sql-server-data-tools

I'm working on a project for my Internship with a collague.
but when he sent me hisasdf(Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise) and I tried to Open his Database, I got the Following Error:

> The database cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>   Could not open new database. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>   An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file {Filename} failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I updated my Sql Server Data Tools to version 14.0.61021.0 and tried again. Unfortunately this didn't work either. (yes I tried turning it off and on again)

So I was wondering if any of you guys could help me out,

Thanks in Advance!

With kind regards,

Yours Truely

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you are trying to attach to a database that is from a newer version of SQL Server than you are using on your machine.

I am thinking that your colleague is using SQL Server 2016 and you are using SQL Server 2014.  See the versions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server) in the "internal version" column.

Regarding solutions, I would start by ensuring that you and you're colleague have the same versions installed.  You can also try downloading [SQL Server 2016 express edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) and opening the database there. You can also try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36951812/574588) as it is a very similar issue.

If you have any questions about this, provide more details on the steps you've taken and I'll be happy to help.