# SQL Server Database Vesion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem regarding a SQL Server database.

The error message is

> Cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

I tried everything, updating via Visual Studio 2015, downloading SQL Server 2016, installing SSMS, but nothing changed the server's version.

I need to somehow change the server's version so it will attach the the database successfully.

Please help!

Comment: How is MySQL relevant? Please remove the tag if it isn't needed. Also where does this error come from? What are you doing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951787/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-851-this-server-supports-ve - May be this question will help.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to attach SQL Server 2016 database files to SQL Server 2014.  This is not supported.

Your only solution is to upgrade SQL Server from 2014 to 2016.  Note, this is the database engine, not management studio.

Here is a list of all SQL Server internal database version numbers: http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html

Comment: Why this question is being answered!! It is blatantly off-topic.