# How to use SQL Server 2016 in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have database file `ex.mdf`; when I tried to connect to this file from Visual Studio 2015, I get error message saying

> Error: This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Hence I tried to install the ssdt tools for the database file which is created in the SQL Server 2016. Even after installing, it is still using SQL Server 2014.

How do I point my Visual Studio 2015 to SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Just like any other version. There are no special requirements. Did you install the latest version of SSDT? Besides, where does this error come from? `782` isn't a SQL Server, SSDT or Visual Studio version

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos even after upgrading to sqlserver2016 i am getting same error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The database cannot be opened because it is version 782. This server supports version 706 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346647/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-782-this-server-supports-ve)

Comment: If you google for this, you'll see it has nothing to do with SQL Server, it's about the LocalDB version used by Visual Studio. This message refers to SQL Explorer and LocalDB

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavoshow do i change my 2014localDB to 2016LocalDB in visual studio?

Comment: I already posted a link to a *duplicate* question. Did you read it?